# php fsockopen timeout is ignored

Tags: php, sockets

I use the PHP function fsockopen to do a http(s) calls.
I can this function with the $timeout argument 5 seconds.

```
$_socket_timeout = 5;
$_fp = @fsockopen ($_server, $_port, $_errno, $_errstr, $_socket_timeout);
```

This code is used to connect to many servers and it works fine except one host.
For that host the timeout is ignored . It can be that this line takes 30,50 and more seconds to execute. Sometimes it is fast.
My script execution timeout is 60 seconds, so sometimes the script is completed with the fatal error on this line because of execution timeout.
I never sow this function returned null and the error code "connection timeout"

What can be the reason? Why the timeout is ignored?
Did anyone experienced such problem?
How to solve?

**UPDATE**
I am sure my code hungs on this place . I modified my code to

```
$_socket_timeout = 5;
$stime = time();
$_fp = @fsockopen ($_server, $_port, $_errno, $_errstr, $_socket_timeout);
logToFile(time()-$stime);
```

**UPDATE 2**
I checked if this problem is DNS problem. it is not. I changed my code to

```
$_socket_timeout = 5;
$stime = time();
$ip = gethostbyname($_server);
logToFile('IP resolve '.time()-$stime);
$_fp = @fsockopen ($ip, $_port, $_errno, $_errstr, $_socket_timeout);
logToFile('connection time '.time()-$stime);
```

And IP resolve works good. but connection is longer 5 seconds sometimes.

Comment: Do you specify that host by it's hostname or by it's IP? If you specify it by it's hostname I would check the DNS response time

Comment: The host is hostname . And also it is ssl like ssl://hostname.com

Comment: I considered DNS problem. but the function gethostbyname always worked fine for that host when i checked

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem continuously? Or does it just happen sporadically?

Comment: No. I can not reproduce the problem continuously. It happens sporadically. It didn't happen for last 3 days at all

Comment: Are you sure that the code hangs at fsockopen? I could imagine that it is not fsockopen, but a read action after the socket has been openend.

Comment: Yes. i a sure. see the question update

Comment: 5 years later and I have the same problem. We have a server that responses very slowly. Most of the time longer then 300s (it's building a very big response). I set the timeout to 900s and it throws timeout after the default `default_socket_timeout`. Even when I do `ini_set('default_socket_timeout', '900')` it's ignored...